# sonarqube plugin is failing from backstage

Tags: backstage

I have added the configuration for app and backend as suggested below.

https://github.com/backstage/backstage/blob/master/plugins/sonarqube/README.md

Still i am unable to fetch the data into backstage

No information to display
There is no SonarQube project with key 'Project-web'.

I see this logs from console

{"error":{"name":"Error","message":"Couldn't find a default sonarqube instance in the config. Either configure an instance with name default or add a prefix to your annotation value.","stack":"Error: Couldn't find a default sonarqube instance in the config. Either configure an instance with name default or add a prefix to your annotation value.\n    at SonarqubeConfig.getInstanceConfig (/app/node_modules/@backstage/plugin-sonarqube-backend/dist/index.cjs.js:116:15)\n    at DefaultSonarqubeInfoProvider.getBaseUrl (/app/node_modules/@backstage/plugin-sonarqube-backend/dist/index.cjs.js:194:40)\n    at /app/node_modules/@backstage/plugin-sonarqube-backend/dist/index.cjs.js:41:47\n    at handleReturn (/app/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:24:23)\n    at /app/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:64:7\n    at handleReturn (/app/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:24:23)\n    at /app/node_modules/express-promise-router/lib/express-promise-router.js:64:7\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)\n    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)\n    at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)"},"request":{"method":"GET","url":"/instanceUrl?instanceKey="},"response":{"statusCode":500}}